# inferring type class constraint when using associated type families

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, type-families

I am aware that [you can add constraints on associated type families and data families](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219162/type-class-constraint-on-type-family-instances). What this does is enforce the constraints on all **instances** of your class.

But I can't figure out how to infer these constraints in **instance derivation or function declarations**. For example, this code fails to type check:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Proxy ( Proxy )

class Eq (FooT a) => Foo a where
    type FooT a :: *

-- Can't infer it in an instance derivation
data CantInferEq a = CantInferEq (FooT a) deriving Eq

-- Also can't infer it in a function declaration.
-- The Proxy is there to avoid non-injectivity issues.
cantInferEq :: Proxy a -> FooT a -> FooT a -> Bool
cantInferEq _ x y = x == y
```

the error messages are:

```
Test.hs:11:52: No instance for (Eq (FooT a)) …
      arising from the first field of ‘CantInferEq’ (type ‘FooT a’)
    Possible fix:
      use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
        so you can specify the instance context yourself
    When deriving the instance for (Eq (CantInferEq a))

Test.hs:16:23: No instance for (Eq (FooT a)) arising from a use of ‘==’ …
    In the expression: x == y
    In an equation for ‘cantInferEq’: cantInferEq _ x y = x == y

Compilation failed.
```

What is going on here? Is there a workaround to get my desired behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crux of the problem is that given just a `FooT a`, you have nowhere to pull the `Eq` instance dictionary from.

The workaround is to be explicit in your typeclass requirements, thereby having a place where the `Eq` dict is passed:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving, UndecidableInstances #-}

data CantInferEq a = CantInferEq (FooT a)    
deriving instance (Eq (FooT a)) => Eq (CantInferEq a)

cantInferEq :: (Eq (FooT a)) => Proxy a -> FooT a -> FooT a -> Bool
cantInferEq _ x y = x == y
```

Or you can avoid having to use `UndecidableInstances` by packaging up the `Eq (FooT a)` dictionary with the `CantInferEq` constructor:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving #-}
data CantInferEq a where
    CantInferEq :: (Eq (FooT a)) => FooT a -> CantInferEq a
deriving instance Eq (CantInferEq a)
```